# Let $f_1$,$f_2$ be two convex functions on $R^n$. Show $\max[f_1(x),f_2(x)]$ is a convex function as well

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-geometry

I'm getting confused on how to prove this. I was thinking 2 points $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the definition of convex function $f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y \le (1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y)$ where $\lambda \subset [0,1]$ and $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, but can't really plug them in cause the values you get back are outputs from a function the function output depends on which function outputs a larger value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of convexity of $f$ is that
$$f((1-t)x+ty)\le (1-t)f(x)+tf(y)\tag{1}$$
for all vectors $x$, $y$ in $\Bbb R^n$ and all $t\in[0,1]$.

In our case, take $f=\max(f_1,f_2)$ where $f_1$, $f_2$ are convex.
Two prove an inequality
$$\max(a,b)\le c$$
it suffices to prove both
$$a\le c\quad \text{and}\quad b\le c.$$
So to prove $(1)$ we only need to prove both
$$f_1((1-t)x+ty)\le (1-t)f(x)+tf(y)\tag{2}$$
and
$$f_2((1-t)x+ty)\le (1-t)f(x)+tf(y).\tag{3}$$

The proofs of $(2)$ and $(3)$ are clearly going to be similar, so I'll
only consider $(2)$. By the convexity of $f_1$ I know that
$$f_1((1-t)x+ty)\le (1-t)f_1(x)+tf_1(y)\tag{4}.$$
But as $1-t\ge0$ and $t\ge0$, and $f_1(x)\le f(x)$
and $f_1(y)\le f(y)$, we have $(1-t)f_1(x)\le (1-t)f(x)$
and $tf_1(y)\le tf(y)$. Thus
$$(1-t)f_1(x)+tf_1(y)\le (1-t)f(x)+tf(y).\tag{5}$$
Putting $(4)$ and $(5)$ together gives $(2)$.

Comment: Brilliant thanks so much! except for the $\le c$ everything else makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\operatorname{epi} \max(f_1,f_2) = \operatorname{epi} f_1 \cap \operatorname{epi} f_2$. The intersection of convex sets is convex.

Comment: what is epi? I actually like this proof except that I don't get how $epi max(f_1,f_2)$ is equal to their intersect

Comment: $\operatorname{epi}  f = \{ (x,\alpha) | \alpha \ge f(x) \}$. A function is convex **iff** its epigraph is convex. It is the points 'above' the graph of $f$.

Comment: That makes sense, but how does the epigraph of the max of 2 functions gives a intersection of the 2 functions? I'd imagine it'd just be the epigraph of whichever is larger no?

Comment: O wait I just imagined it in my head and now I see it